# Display PDF in Excel VBA UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, adobe

I am running Excel 2016, which may be relevant if the below is a compatibility issue...

**In short, I am trying to display a PDF, embedded in a UserForm in Excel.**

I have a UserForm, say `UserForm1`.

I have enabled the following extra references:

- Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3
- Adobe Acrobat Browser Control Type Library 1.0

This allows me to add the `Adobe PDF Reader` as an "Additional Control"

[image: Additional Controls dialog]

The control appears as a hatched box icon (bottom left), which I'm not sure it's meant to. Then if I try to add one of these objects to `UserForm1` (both programmatically and in design view) it gives me an error

> Element not found

For reference, the relevant lines of VBA I was using were:

```
Dim PDFviewer As AcroPDF
Set PDFviewer = PDForm.Frame1.Controls.Add("AcroPDF.PDF.1")
```

Which I took from this Adobe forums thread: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1065554

Resources online suggest it might be that the AcroPDF control is no longer supported. If so, is there another way to achieve what I want?

Comment: One alternative could be  to try is Add a browser control and then use Iframe to show the PDF.

Comment: I'll have to look into the browser control, from the mention of an IFrame, I guess this gets manipulated through HTML then?

Comment: yes, you will create a html string on the flyy with the pdf path and write to browser control's document.

Comment: Brilliant! Turns out I didn't even need to faff with any HTML, can directly reference the path of the PDF with the `BrowserControl.Navigate <path>` command.Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Great, but its safe to use the html part, depending on the machine settings, some times direct navigation will initiate download instead of display. Rare as web browser control is still IE7 but possible. Plus 2 lines of code are not so much work :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As an alternative to using the `AcroPDF`, try using the `WebBrowser` Object.

It requires including the additional control

`Microsoft Web Browser`

Add a WeBrowser on the UserForm named `WebBrowser1`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate "about:blank"
    Me.WebBrowser1.Document.write "<HTML><Body><embed src=""C:\temp\SO_Answers\test.pdf"" width=""100%"" height=""100%"" /></Body></HTML>"
End Sub
```

You can just `.Navigate` to the PDF directly, but, to quote my comment:

*"It's safer to use the html part, depending on the machine settings, sometimes direct navigation will initiate download instead of display."*

Comment: Hello, is it possible to show a pdf from a value in a textbox?

Comment: The files will be all in the same folder.

Comment: yes. you can. Iterate over the folder location and then create a string with each pdf file name and then pass the full path as `src`.

Comment: This only works ONCE in the code below..after that it doesn't display the PDF...any idea why it doesn't work after that?

    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate "about:blank" 'Will cause error if removed
If IsIn(".pdf", FullPath) Then Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Write "<HTML><Body><embed src=" & """" & FullPath & """" & "width=""125%"" height=""125%"" /></Body></HTML>": Exit Sub
If IsIn(".txt", FullPath) Then Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate "file:///" & Replace(FullPath, "\", "/"): Exit Sub
Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate Get_URL(FullPath)

Comment: Both trying to navigate to the page and embedding it result in it trying to initiate download instead of displaying. Is there a work around for this?