# Displaying a pdf file using web browser object and the CurrentProject.Path Property to load the file on a form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am Using a web browser object to browse to the pdf file on form load event.
The file lives in thae same folder as the front-end.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have tried `CurrentProject.Path & "\Internal Framework Summary.pdf"` with no luck.
The code is:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim Thefile As String
Thefile = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Internal Framework Summary.pdf"
Me.web1Control.Object.Navigate Thefile
End Sub
```

Comment: no luck meaning what? `Thefile` exists but you are not able to see that in your web1Control?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292195/display-pdf-in-excel-vba-userform

Comment: @cyboashu Yes I cant see it on web1Control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have learnt that using the code on the form open event by itself doesn't work sometimes. It doesn't work on the form load event either. As a result I have created a module

```
Sub loadPDFFile()
Dim webBrowser2 As WebBrowser
Dim pdfPath As String
Set webBrowser2 = webControl.Object
pdfPath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Internal Framework Summary.pdf"
webBrowser2.Navigate pdfFilePath
End Sub
```

Then on the Form Open event:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Me.webControl.ControlSource = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Internal Framework Summary.pdf" 
End Sub
```

Finally on the Form Load event:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
loadpdf
End Sub
```

This seems to be working now but I am not sure if there is a better and more efficient way of doing it.